# Using a Raspberry Pi Pico, MCP 2515 and Micropython to transmit frames over CAN

Tags: can-bus, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi Pico and MCP 2515 to transmit frames over CAN. For this I'm using CAN bus Module (B) for Raspberry Pi Pico (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-CAN-B) and demo code for micropython from the same page (code below).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from machine import Pin,SPI,PWM
import time

## Configuration Registers */
CANSTAT      = 0x0E
CANCTRL      = 0x0F
BFPCTRL      = 0x0C
TEC          = 0x1C
REC          = 0x1D
CNF3         = 0x28
CNF2         = 0x29
CNF1         = 0x2A
CANINTE      = 0x2B
CANINTF      = 0x2C
EFLG         = 0x2D
TXRTSCTRL    = 0x0D

##  Recieve Filters */
RXF0SIDH     = 0x00
RXF0SIDL     = 0x01
RXF0EID8     = 0x02
RXF0EID0     = 0x03
RXF1SIDH     = 0x04
RXF1SIDL     = 0x05
RXF1EID8     = 0x06
RXF1EID0     = 0x07
RXF2SIDH     = 0x08
RXF2SIDL     = 0x09
RXF2EID8     = 0x0A
RXF2EID0     = 0x0B
RXF3SIDH     = 0x10
RXF3SIDL     = 0x11
RXF3EID8     = 0x12
RXF3EID0     = 0x13
RXF4SIDH     = 0x14
RXF4SIDL     = 0x15
RXF4EID8     = 0x16
RXF4EID0     = 0x17
RXF5SIDH     = 0x18
RXF5SIDL     = 0x19
RXF5EID8     = 0x1A
RXF5EID0     = 0x1B

## Receive Masks */
RXM0SIDH     = 0x20
RXM0SIDL     = 0x21
RXM0EID8     = 0x22
RXM0EID0     = 0x23
RXM1SIDH     = 0x24
RXM1SIDL     = 0x25
RXM1EID8     = 0x26
RXM1EID0     = 0x27

## Tx Buffer 0 */
TXB0CTRL     = 0x30
TXB0SIDH     = 0x31
TXB0SIDL     = 0x32
TXB0EID8     = 0x33
TXB0EID0     = 0x34
TXB0DLC      = 0x35
TXB0D0       = 0x36
TXB0D1       = 0x37
TXB0D2       = 0x38
TXB0D3       = 0x39
TXB0D4       = 0x3A
TXB0D5       = 0x3B
TXB0D6       = 0x3C
TXB0D7       = 0x3D

## Tx Buffer 1 */
TXB1CTRL     = 0x40
TXB1SIDH     = 0x41
TXB1SIDL     = 0x42
TXB1EID8     = 0x43
TXB1EID0     = 0x44
TXB1DLC      = 0x45
TXB1D0       = 0x46
TXB1D1       = 0x47
TXB1D2       = 0x48
TXB1D3       = 0x49
TXB1D4       = 0x4A
TXB1D5       = 0x4B
TXB1D6       = 0x4C
TXB1D7       = 0x4D

## Tx Buffer 2 */
TXB2CTRL     = 0x50
TXB2SIDH     = 0x51
TXB2SIDL     = 0x52
TXB2EID8     = 0x53
TXB2EID0     = 0x54
TXB2DLC      = 0x55
TXB2D0       = 0x56
TXB2D1       = 0x57
TXB2D2       = 0x58
TXB2D3       = 0x59
TXB2D4       = 0x5A
TXB2D5       = 0x5B
TXB2D6       = 0x5C
TXB2D7       = 0x5D

# ## Rx Buffer 0 */
RXB0CTRL     = 0x60
RXB0SIDH     = 0x61
RXB0SIDL     = 0x62
RXB0EID8     = 0x63
RXB0EID0     = 0x64
RXB0DLC      = 0x65
RXB0D0       = 0x66
RXB0D1       = 0x67
RXB0D2       = 0x68
RXB0D3       = 0x69
RXB0D4       = 0x6A
RXB0D5       = 0x6B
RXB0D6       = 0x6C
RXB0D7       = 0x6D

# ## Rx Buffer 1 */
RXB1CTRL     = 0x70
RXB1SIDH     = 0x71
RXB1SIDL     = 0x72
RXB1EID8     = 0x73
RXB1EID0     = 0x74
RXB1DLC      = 0x75
RXB1D0       = 0x76
RXB1D1       = 0x77
RXB1D2       = 0x78
RXB1D3       = 0x79
RXB1D4       = 0x7A
RXB1D5       = 0x7B
RXB1D6       = 0x7C
RXB1D7       = 0x7D


# ##******************************************************************
 # *               Bit register masks                                *
 # *******************************************************************/

# ## TXBnCTRL */
TXREQ        = 0x08
TXP          = 0x03

# ## RXBnCTRL */
RXM          = 0x60
BUKT         = 0x04

# ## CANCTRL */
REQOP        = 0xE0
ABAT         = 0x10
#define OSM          = 0x08
CLKEN        = 0x04
CLKPRE       = 0x03

# ## CANSTAT */
REQOP        = 0xE0
ICOD         = 0x0E

## CANINTE */
RX0IE        = 0x01
RX1IE        = 0x02
TX0IE        = 0x04
TX1IE        = 0x80
TX2IE        = 0x10
ERRIE        = 0x20
WAKIE        = 0x40
MERRE        = 0x80

# ## CANINTF */
RX0IF        = 0x01
RX1IF        = 0x02
TX0IF        = 0x04
TX1IF        = 0x80
TX2IF        = 0x10
ERRIF        = 0x20
WAKIF        = 0x40
MERRF        = 0x80

# ## BFPCTRL */
B1BFS        = 0x20
B0BFS        = 0x10
B1BFE        = 0x08
B0BFE        = 0x04
B1BFM        = 0x02
B0BFM        = 0x01

# ## CNF1 Masks */
SJW          = 0xC0
BRP          = 0x3F

# ## CNF2 Masks */
BTLMODE      = 0x80
SAM          = 0x40
PHSEG1       = 0x38
PRSEG        = 0x07

# ## CNF3 Masks */
WAKFIL       = 0x40
PHSEG2       = 0x07

# ## TXRTSCTRL Masks */
TXB2RTS      = 0x04
TXB1RTS      = 0x02
TXB0RTS      = 0x01


# ##******************************************************************
 # *                    Bit Timing Configuration                     *
 # *******************************************************************/
 
# ## CNF1 */
SJW_1TQ      = 0x40
SJW_2TQ      = 0x80
SJW_3TQ      = 0x90
SJW_4TQ      = 0xC0

# ## CNF2 */
BTLMODE_CNF3 = 0x80
BTLMODE_PH1_IPT  = 0x00

SMPL_3X      = 0x40
SMPL_1X      = 0x00

PHSEG1_8TQ   = 0x38
PHSEG1_7TQ   = 0x30
PHSEG1_6TQ   = 0x28
PHSEG1_5TQ   = 0x20
PHSEG1_4TQ   = 0x18
PHSEG1_3TQ   = 0x10
PHSEG1_2TQ   = 0x08
PHSEG1_1TQ   = 0x00

PRSEG_8TQ    = 0x07
PRSEG_7TQ    = 0x06
PRSEG_6TQ    = 0x05
PRSEG_5TQ    = 0x04
PRSEG_4TQ    = 0x03
PRSEG_3TQ    = 0x02
PRSEG_2TQ    = 0x01
PRSEG_1TQ    = 0x00

# ## CNF3 */
PHSEG2_8TQ   = 0x07
PHSEG2_7TQ   = 0x06
PHSEG2_6TQ   = 0x05
PHSEG2_5TQ   = 0x04
PHSEG2_4TQ   = 0x03
PHSEG2_3TQ   = 0x02
PHSEG2_2TQ   = 0x01
PHSEG2_1TQ   = 0x00

SOF_ENABLED  = 0x80
WAKFIL_ENABLED  =0x40
WAKFIL_DISABLED =0x00


# ##******************************************************************
 # *                  Control/Configuration Registers                *
 # *******************************************************************/

# ## CANINTE */
RX0IE_ENABLED= 0x01
RX0IE_DISABLED  =0x00
RX1IE_ENABLED =0x02
RX1IE_DISABLED  =0x00
G_RXIE_ENABLED  =0x03
G_RXIE_DISABLED =0x00

TX0IE_ENABLED= 0x04
TX0IE_DISABLED  =0x00
TX1IE_ENABLED =0x08
TX2IE_DISABLED  =0x00
TX2IE_ENABLED =0x10
TX2IE_DISABLED  =0x00
G_TXIE_ENABLED  =0x1C
G_TXIE_DISABLED =0x00

ERRIE_ENABLED= 0x20
ERRIE_DISABLED  =0x00
WAKIE_ENABLED= 0x40
WAKIE_DISABLED  =0x00
IVRE_ENABLED = 0x80
IVRE_DISABLED= 0x00

# ## CANINTF */
RX0IF_SET    = 0x01
RX0IF_RESET  = 0x00
RX1IF_SET    = 0x02
RX1IF_RESET  = 0x00
TX0IF_SET    = 0x04
TX0IF_RESET  = 0x00
TX1IF_SET    = 0x08
TX2IF_RESET  = 0x00
TX2IF_SET    = 0x10
TX2IF_RESET  = 0x00
ERRIF_SET    = 0x20
ERRIF_RESET  = 0x00
WAKIF_SET    = 0x40
WAKIF_RESET  = 0x00
IVRF_SET     = 0x80
IVRF_RESET   = 0x00

# ## CANCTRL */ 
REQOP_CONFIG = 0x80
REQOP_LISTEN = 0x60
REQOP_LOOPBACK  =0x40
REQOP_SLEEP  = 0x20
REQOP_NORMAL = 0x00

ABORT        = 0x10

OSM_ENABLED  = 0x08

CLKOUT_ENABLED  =0x04
CLKOUT_DISABLED =0x00
CLKOUT_PRE_8 = 0x03
CLKOUT_PRE_4 = 0x02
CLKOUT_PRE_2 = 0x01
CLKOUT_PRE_1 = 0x00

# ## CANSTAT */
OPMODE_CONFIG= 0x80
OPMODE_LISTEN= 0x60
OPMODE_LOOPBACK =0x40
OPMODE_SLEEP = 0x20
OPMODE_NORMAL= 0x00


# ## RXBnCTRL */
RXM_RCV_ALL  = 0x60
RXM_VALID_EXT= 0x40
RXM_VALID_STD= 0x20
RXM_VALID_ALL= 0x00

RXRTR_REMOTE = 0x08
RXRTR_NO_REMOTE =0x00

BUKT_ROLLOVER = 0x04
BUKT_NO_ROLLOVER =0x00

FILHIT0_FLTR_1  =0x01
FILHIT0_FLTR_0  =0x00

FILHIT1_FLTR_5  =0x05
FILHIT1_FLTR_4  =0x04
FILHIT1_FLTR_3  =0x03
FILHIT1_FLTR_2  =0x02
FILHIT1_FLTR_1  =0x01
FILHIT1_FLTR_0  =0x00


# ## TXBnCTRL */
TXREQ_SET    = 0x08
TXREQ_CLEAR  = 0x00

TXP_HIGHEST  = 0x03
TXP_INTER_HIGH  =0x02
TXP_INTER_LOW= 0x01
TXP_LOWEST   = 0x00
    

# ##******************************************************************
 # *                  Register Bit Masks                             *
 # *******************************************************************/
 
DLC_0       = 0x00
DLC_1       = 0x01
DLC_2       = 0x02
DLC_3       = 0x03
DLC_4       = 0x04
DLC_5       = 0x05
DLC_6       = 0x06
DLC_7       = 0x07    
DLC_8       = 0x08


# ##******************************************************************
 # *                  CAN spi commands                               *
 # *******************************************************************/

CAN_RESET    = 0xC0
CAN_READ     = 0x03
CAN_WRITE    = 0x02
CAN_RTS      = 0x80
CAN_RTS_TXB0 = 0x81
CAN_RTS_TXB1 = 0x82
CAN_RTS_TXB2 = 0x84
CAN_RD_STATUS= 0xA0
CAN_BIT_MODIFY  =0x05  
CAN_RX_STATUS= 0xB0
CAN_RD_RX_BUFF  =0x90
CAN_LOAD_TX  = 0x40  


# ##******************************************************************
 # *                  Miscellaneous                                  *
 # *******************************************************************/

DUMMY_BYTE   = 0x00
TXB0         = 0x31
TXB1         = 0x41
TXB2         = 0x51
RXB0         = 0x61
RXB1         = 0x71
EXIDE_SET    = 0x08
EXIDE_RESET  = 0x00
# #CS   PORTAbits.RA2

CAN_RATE = {
    "5KBPS"   : [0xA7, 0XBF, 0x07],
    "10KBPS"  : [0x31, 0XA4, 0X04],
    "20KBPS"  : [0x18, 0XA4, 0x04],
    "50KBPS"  : [0x09, 0XA4, 0x04],
    "100KBPS" : [0x04, 0x9E, 0x03],
    "125KBPS" : [0x03, 0x9E, 0x03],
    "250KBPS" : [0x01, 0x1E, 0x03],
    "500KBPS" : [0x00, 0x9E, 0x03],
    "800KBPS" : [0x00, 0x92, 0x02],
    "1000KBPS": [0x00, 0x82, 0x02],
}

gRXFlag=0
sRXFlag=0
yRXFlag=0
Com_RecBuff = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #8
# data = 0

SPI0_CS1 = 1
SPI0_CS0 = 5

debug = False
# debug = True
class MCP2515():
    def __init__(self):
        self.spi = SPI(0)
        self.spi = SPI(0,250000,polarity=0, phase=0,sck=Pin(6),mosi=Pin(7),miso=Pin(4))
        self.cs = Pin(SPI0_CS0,Pin.OUT)
        
    def ReadByte(self, addr):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([CAN_READ]))
        self.spi.write(bytearray([addr]))
        res = self.spi.read(1)
        self.cs(1)
        return int.from_bytes(res,'big')
    def WriteByte(self, addr):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([addr]))
        self.cs(1)
    def WriteBytes(self, addr, data):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([CAN_WRITE]))
        self.spi.write(bytearray([addr]))
        self.spi.write(bytearray([data]))
        self.cs(1)
    def Reset(self):
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([CAN_RESET])) #Reset 0XC0
        self.cs(1)
        
    def Init(self, speed="125KBPS"):
        print("Reset")
        self.Reset()
        time.sleep(0.1)
            
        #set baud rate 125Kbps
        #<7:6>SJW=00(1TQ)
        #<5:0>BRP=0x03 (TQ=[2*(BRP+1)]/Fsoc=2*4/8M=1us)
        #<5:0>BRP=0x03 (TQ=[2*(BRP+1)]/Fsoc=2*8/16M=1us)
        # self.WriteBytes(CNF1, 7)      
        # self.WriteBytes(CNF2,0x80|PHSEG1_3TQ|PRSEG_1TQ)       
        # self.WriteBytes(CNF3,PHSEG2_3TQ)
        self.WriteBytes(CNF1, CAN_RATE[speed][0])
        self.WriteBytes(CNF2, CAN_RATE[speed][1])
        self.WriteBytes(CNF3, CAN_RATE[speed][2])       

        #set TXB0,TXB1
        #<15:5> SID 11bit canid
        #<BIT3> exide,1:extended 0:standard
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0SIDH,0xFF)
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0SIDL,0xE0)
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0DLC,0x40|DLC_8)
        # self.WriteBytes(TXB1SIDH,0x50)
        # self.WriteBytes(TXB1SIDL,0x00)
        # self.WriteBytes(TXB1DLC,0x40 | DLC_8)    #Set DLC = 3 bytes and RTR bit*/

        #Set RX
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0SIDH,0x00)
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0SIDL,0x60)
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0CTRL,0x60)
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0DLC, DLC_8)

        self.WriteBytes(RXF0SIDH,0xFF)
        self.WriteBytes(RXF0SIDL,0xE0)
        self.WriteBytes(RXM0SIDH,0xFF)
        self.WriteBytes(RXM0SIDL,0xE0)

        #can int
        self.WriteBytes(CANINTF,0x00)#clean interrupt flag
        self.WriteBytes(CANINTE,0x01)#Receive Buffer 0 Full Interrupt Enable Bit

        self.WriteBytes(CANCTRL, REQOP_NORMAL|CLKOUT_ENABLED)#

        dummy=self.ReadByte(CANSTAT)
        if( OPMODE_NORMAL != (dummy and 0xE0)):
            self.WriteBytes(CANCTRL, REQOP_NORMAL|CLKOUT_ENABLED)#set normal mode

    def Send(self, CAN_ID, CAN_TX_Buf, length1):
        tempdata = self.ReadByte(CAN_RD_STATUS)
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0SIDH, (CAN_ID>>3)&0XFF)
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0SIDL, (CAN_ID&0x07)<<5)
        
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0EID8, 0)
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0EID0, 0)
        self.WriteBytes(TXB0DLC, length1)
        for j in range(0, length1): 
            self.WriteBytes(TXB0D0+j,CAN_TX_Buf[j])

        if(tempdata&0x04):# TXREQ
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.WriteBytes(TXB0CTRL, 0)#clean flag
            while(1):#wite 
                if(self.ReadByte(CAN_RD_STATUS)&0x04 != 1):
                    break
        self.WriteByte(CAN_RTS_TXB0)

    def Receive(self, CAN_ID):
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0SIDH, (CAN_ID>>3)&0XFF)
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0SIDL, (CAN_ID&0x07)<<5)
        CAN_RX_Buf = []
        while(1):
            if(self.ReadByte(CANINTF) & 0x01):
                len = self.ReadByte(RXB0DLC)
                print(len)
                for i in range(0, len): 
                    CAN_RX_Buf.append(hex(self.ReadByte(RXB0D0+i)))
                    # print(self.ReadByte(RXB0D0+i))
                break

        self.WriteBytes(CANINTF, 0)
        self.WriteBytes(CANINTE,0x01)#enable
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0SIDH,0x00)#clean
        self.WriteBytes(RXB0SIDL,0x60)
        return CAN_RX_Buf
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
    can = MCP2515()
    print("init...")
    can.Init()
    print("send data...")
    id = 0x123 #max 7ff
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    dlc = 8
    can.Send(id, data, dlc)
    
    
    readbuf = []
    # while(1):
    while(1):
        readbuf = can.Receive(id)
        print(readbuf)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

In this demo code the maximum frame id value is limited to 0x7ff. What is the reason for this and how to remove this restriction? I need to send frames with id 0x18FD6A0A.

Comment: Because: CAN. The most common frame format uses 11 bit identifier. 29 bit identifier is less common, so it probably would just confuse people needlessly if examples were using 29 bit identifier. As for how to configure dinosaur technology like MCP2515 to use 29 bit identifiers, I have no idea. Consider using a more suitable microcontroller with built-in CAN controller instead. Using external controllers is self-torture (and needlessly expensive).